# Changing format html/css to react but the layout not working properly

Tags: reactjs

I just get started learning React, so I am a pretty beginner. Few days ago, I clone the Instagram main page(feed part) code in HTML/CSS and I tried to change HTML/CSS to React but when I just copy and past login part(this is pretty short code / editing a little bit in JSX syntax) it works as well. However, when I copy and paste main.js and .css. file, the layout totally not working what I expected.
I will leave my code below!

This is main.js

In this part "input class="search-box" type="text" placeholder=" Search",style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome" I delete style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome because react show this part error

I change name --> nameClass but same error..[image]

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import "./Main.css";

class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div class="wrapper"> 
                    <div class="nav">
                        <p class="logo"> Westagram </p>
                        <input class="search-box" type="text" placeholder="&#xF002; Search",style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome />
                        <div class="icons">
                            <img id="compass" src="https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.wecode.co.kr/bearu/explore.png" />
                            <img id="heart" src="https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.wecode.co.kr/bearu/heart.png" /> 
                            <img id="my-page" src=" https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.wecode.co.kr/bearu/profile.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    <div class="main">
                        <div class="feeds">
                            <div class="article">
                                <div class="identi">
                                    <img class="selfi" src="../src/assets/images/about.png" /> 
                                    <span class="name"> Jiwan Jeon </span>
                                    
                                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </div>

                                <div class="pic">
                                    <img src="../src/assets/images/ucscPic.png" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="show-box">
                                    <div class="reaction-icons">
                                        <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-send-o"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="like-counts">
                                        <span>like 4,000</span>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="check-comments">
                                        <span>UC Santa Cruz will continue to offer most courses remotely or online for spring and summer 2021, providing in-person instruction for a small</span>
                                        <a id="space" href="">expanding</a><br />
                                        <a href="">Check the all comments</a>
                                        <ul class="feed-comments">
                                            <li>test</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="comment">
                                    <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
                                    <input class="user-input" type="text" placeholder="Add Comment..." />
                                    <button class="post">Post</button>
                                </div>
 
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="main-right">
                        <div class="top">
                            <img class="selfi" src="../src/assets/images/about.png" />
                            <div class="main-right-name">
                                <span id="eng-name">JiwanJeon94</span><br />
                                <span id="kr-name">전지완</span>
                            </div>
                            
                            <a href="">Transform</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="middle">
                            <div class="middle-words">
                                <span id="recommendation">Suggestions For You</span>
                                <a href="" id="view-all">view all</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="recommendation-people">
                                <div id="recommendation-section1">
                                    <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="../src/assets/images/about.png" />
                                    <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                                    <a href="">Follow</a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="recommendation-section1">
                                    <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="../src/assets/images/about.png" />
                                    <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                                    <a href="">Follow</a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="recommendation-section1">
                                    <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="../src/assets/images/about.png" />
                                    <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                                    <a href="">Follow</a>
                                </div>  
                                <div id="recommendation-section1">
                                    <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="../src/assets/images/about.png" />
                                    <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                                    <a href="">Follow</a>
                                </div>                  
                                <div id="recommendation-section1">
                                    <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="../src/assets/images/about.png" />
                                    <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                                    <a href="">Follow</a>
                                </div>                                                  
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="footer">
                            <div class="footer-top">
                                <a  href="">About</a>
                                <a  href="">Help</a>            
                                <a  href="">press</a>
                                <a  href="">API</a>     
                                <a  href="">Jobs</a>        
                                <a  href="">Privacy</a> 
                                <a  href="">Terms</a>   
                                <a  href="">Locations</a>       
                                <a  href="">TopAccounts</a> 
                                <a  href="">Hashtags</a>    
                                <a  href="">Language</a><br /><br />    
                            </div>  
                        </div>          
                        <span>2021 INSTAGRAM FROM FACEBOOK</span>
                    </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

This is CSS code

```
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
  /*what does box-sizing: border-box; doing "check"*/
}

@font-face {
  font-family: instagramFont;
  src:  url("./westagram.ttf") format("opentype");
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  height: 100%;

}

.wrapper .nav {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #dbdbdb;

  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  /*포지션 여러개 썼을때 우선순위 설정 인덱스값이 클수록 우선순위*/
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper .nav .logo {
  font-family: instagramFont;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding-right : 100px;
}

.search-box {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 215px;
  height: 28px;
}

.wrapper .nav .icons {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.wrapper .main {
  position: relative;
  /*포지션을 쓰면 위치 조정 top left right bottom*/
  top: 70px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 
}

.wrapper .main .feeds {
  position: relative;
  
  top: 40px;
  right: 5px;
  left: 61px;
  width: 60%;

  background-color: yellow;
  
}
.wrapper .main .feeds .article {
  position: absolute;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid 1px #dbdbdb; 
  height: 954px;
  width: 614px;

}
.wrapper .main .feeds .article .identi {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;

}

.wrapper .main .feeds .article .identi .selfi {
  padding: 15px 20px 20px 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;

}
.wrapper .main .feeds .article .identi .name {
  padding-top: 23px;
  padding-right: 410px;

}

.wrapper .main .feeds .article .identi .fa {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}


.wrapper .main .feeds .article .pic {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 0px;


}

.wrapper .main .feeds .article .pic img {
  width: 614px;
  height: 614px;
  padding: 5px 0px 2px 0px;
}

.wrapper .main .feeds .article .show-box{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;


  padding: 5px 0px 20px 0px;
  height: 170px;
}

.show-box .reaction-icons .fa-comment-o {
  font-size: 30px;

  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.show-box .reaction-icons .fa-heart-o {
  font-size: 30px;

  padding-left: 10px;
}

.show-box .reaction-icons .fa-send-o {
  font-size: 30px;

  padding-left: 10px;
}

.show-box .reaction-icons .fa-bookmark-o {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 450px;
}

.wrapper .main .feeds .article .comment {
  position: relative;

  margin-top: 75px;
  /*padding: 3px 0px 3px 0px;*/
/*top값을 줘야하는 이유 relative이기 때문에 자동으로 배열돼야하는데 그렇지 않음
그랫서 show-box에 height값을 따로줌*/
  /*height: 30px;height: 20%;*/

}

.wrapper .main .feeds .article #post {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 25px;
  border: solid 1px #D3D3D3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*background-color: #ff000;*/
  background-color: #B2DFFC;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*padding-left: 15px;*/
}

.wrapper .main .feeds .article .show-box .like-counts {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.check-comments{

}

.wrapper .main .feeds .article .comment i {
  font-size: 30px;

}
.wrapper .main .feeds .article .comment input {
  width: 530px;
  height: 20px;

}
.wrapper .main .feeds .article .comment span {
  margin-left: 5px;

}
.wrapper .main-right {
  position: fixed;
  top: 11.9%;
  right: 4%; 
  width: 28%;
  height: 98%;
  

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}

.wrapper .main .main-right .top{
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 3px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.wrapper .main .main-right .top .selfi {
  padding: 15px 20px 20px 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;  
}

.wrapper .main .main-right .top .main-right-name {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.wrapper .main .main-right .top .main-right-name #eng-name {

}

.wrapper .main .main-right .top .main-right-name #kr-name {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.wrapper .main .main-right a {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.wrapper .main .main-right .middle{
  height: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
 
}

.wrapper .main .main-right .middle .middle-words {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.wrapper .main .main-right .middle .middle-words #recommendation {
  margin-left: 23px;
}

.wrapper .main .main-right .middle .middle-words #view-all {
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.wrapper .main .main-right .middle .recommendation-people {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper .main .main-right .middle .recommendation-people #recommendation-section1 #recommendation-people-selfi{
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.wrapper .main .main-right .middle .recommendation-people #recommendation-section1 span {
  position: relative;
  right: 5px;
  top: -18px;

}

.wrapper .main .main-right .middle .recommendation-people #recommendation-section1 a {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  

}
.wrapper .main .main-right .footer {

  margin-left: 10px;

}

.wrapper .main .main-right .footer .footer-nav{
  margin-left: 5px;

}

.wrapper .main .main-right .footer .footer-nav .footer-top {

}

.wrapper .main .main-right .footer a {
  opacity: 0.3;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
}

.wrapper .main .main-right .footer span {
  opacity: 0.3;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#compass {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
 
}

#heart {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

#my-page {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;

}

#space {
  padding-top: 400px;
}
```

This is my HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Westagram Main Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/main.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/common.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- header : segmantic tag -->

    <div class="wrapper"> 
        <div class="nav">
            <p class="logo"> Westagram </p>
            <input class="search-box" type="text" placeholder="&#xF002; Search", style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome">
            <div class="icons">
                <img id="compass" src="https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.wecode.co.kr/bearu/explore.png" >
                <img id="heart" src="https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.wecode.co.kr/bearu/heart.png" > 
                <img id="my-page" src=" https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.wecode.co.kr/bearu/profile.png">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main">
            <div class="feeds">
                <div class="article">
                    <div class="identi">
                        <img class="selfi" src="../src/about.png"> 
                        <span class="name"> Jiwan Jeon </span>
                        <!-- 이름 두줄로 나오는거 해결할 -->
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pic">
                        <img src="../src/ucscPic.png">
                    </div>

                    <div class="show-box">
                        <div class="reaction-icons">
                            <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-send-o"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="like-counts">
                            <span>like 4,000</span>
                        <div>

                        <div class="check-comments">
                            <span>UC Santa Cruz will continue to offer most courses remotely or online for spring and summer 2021, providing in-person instruction for a small</span>
                            <a id="space" href="">expanding</a><br>
                            <a href="">Check the all comments</a>
                            <ul class="feed-comments">
                                <li>test</li>
                            </ul>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="comment">
                        <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
                        <input class="user-input" type="text" placeholder="Add Comment...">
                        <button class="post">Post</button>
                    </div>

                    
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main-right">
            <div class="top">
                <img class="selfi" src="../src/about.png">
                <div class="main-right-name">
                    <span id="eng-name">JiwanJeon94</span><br>
                    <span id="kr-name">전지완</span>
                </div>
                
                <a href="">Transform</a>
            </div>

            <div class="middle">
                <div class="middle-words">
                    <span id="recommendation">Suggestions For You</span>
                    <a href="" id="view-all">view all</a>
                </div>
                <div class="recommendation-people">
                    <div id="recommendation-section1">
                        <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="../src/about.png">
                        <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                        <a href="">Follow</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="recommendation-section1">
                        <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="../src/about.png">
                        <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                        <a href="">Follow</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="recommendation-section1">
                        <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="../src/about.png">
                        <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                        <a href="">Follow</a>
                    </div>  
                    <div id="recommendation-section1">
                        <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="../src/about.png">
                        <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                        <a href="">Follow</a>
                    </div>                  
                    <div id="recommendation-section1">
                        <img id="recommendation-people-selfi" src="../src/about.png">
                        <span>Recommendation for you</span>
                        <a href="">Follow</a>
                    </div>                                                  
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="footer">
                <div class="footer-top">
                    <a  href="">About</a>
                    <a  href="">Help</a>            
                    <a  href="">press</a>
                    <a  href="">API</a>     
                    <a  href="">Jobs</a>        
                    <a  href="">Privacy</a> 
                    <a  href="">Terms</a>   
                    <a  href="">Locations</a>       
                    <a  href="">TopAccounts</a> 
                    <a  href="">Hashtags</a>    
                    <a  href="">Language</a><br><br>    
            </div>              
            <span>2021 INSTAGRAM FROM FACEBOOK</span>
            <script src="../js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First, you need to test the layout in html, css with this code. If it's correct, then you have to include it in React. Also in React, you want to load an image then you should use source={url}, the class name will be className.

Comment: @Trung It totally works in HTML and CSS! I assume that the img not work but I guess the layout should be work in React but it is not working in React when I copy and past in React

Comment: You also should replace class by className as this should be jsx syntax, not html. There are also pages that help you to replace your html code by react jsx syntax

Comment: @DOeat Please attach the html file. Have you declared <!DOCTYPE html> for the html file?

Comment: @Trung Thank you for pointing out! I edit my post and adding my HTML file. My login page part works well even I didn't include <!DOCTYPE HTML> in react... it's weird